# Ruby on Rails - How do I prevent my assets from being loaded twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, railstutorial.org

**Preface**: I'm doing the Rails Tutorial from [railstutorial.org](http://www.railstutorial.org). I've already tried to fix the issue (which is that my bootstrap-dropdown menu isn't opening) but in my search I believe I uncovered a greater issue which I cannot seem to solve.

**The Problem**: My rails app seems to be loading every .js  and .css file twice. As in:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="JJWsUII950M/WG8p2CUTI1nuCgDCPLmJAC5yCHl1uec=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="JJWsUII950M/WG8p2CUTI1nuCgDCPLmJAC5yCHl1uec=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
  </head>
```

So, I've already done rake assets:clean. I added the line config.serve_static_assets = false  to my development.rb.

Neither of these worked. My issue is at the local level and at heroku.

Here's my [git](https://github.com/nelsonkhan/sample_app) and my [heroku](https://guarded-shelf-3017.herokuapp.com/) links - you can see I've been trying to fix this but I've really had no luck.

Some more files to look at (maybe itll help?)

application.css

```
*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $grayLight;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  &:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  color: $grayLight;
  a {
    color: #555;
    &:hover { 
    color: #222;
    }
  }  
small {
  float: left;
}
ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
    li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
 }
}

/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input {
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: #f00;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .control-group;
  @extend .error;
}
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'

end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  # System-dependent gems
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have following extra block of code in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, hence the reason for duplicate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Remove that and you should be good to go.